# NHibernate session closing unexpectedly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, fluent-nhibernate, castle-windsor

I am using a MVC4, C#, Castle Windsor, fluentnhibernate stack for my web application, which generally works very well.

Its only occasionally that I get an error related to nHibernate something along the lines of:

> Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed.

or

> Internal connection fatal error.

This usually rears its ugly head when I do multiple calls, in very close succession.

Currently I am replicating it while doing multiple ajax gets, from JQuery.

What I suspect the problem is, is with my NHibernate session management.

The only thing I can think of is that the calls are someone using the ***same*** session, the first one completes and closes it, then the following call is unable to complete.

This shouldn't be possible due to the way my sessions are handled like this:

```
Kernel.Register(
                Component.For<ISessionFactory>()
                                .UsingFactoryMethod(_ => config.BuildSessionFactory()),
                Component.For<ISession>()
                                .UsingFactoryMethod(k => k.Resolve<ISessionFactory>().OpenSession())
                                .LifestylePerWebRequest());
```

Should be one session per request right?

How else, or where else can I look for the problem? I am quite stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course solved this a few minutes later, but the answer was an eye opener for me.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4561223/148998) led me down the right path.

While all of my Repositories, Manager and other layers were installed with the correct lifestyle using Castle Windsor, there was one that wasn't.

I was doing a Repository call from an ActionFilter, all of my action filters are invoked through an ActionInvoker class which was registered incorrectly as Singleton, which resulted in my errors.

```
container.Register(Component.For<IActionInvoker>()
                                    .ImplementedBy<WindsorActionInvoker>()
                                    .LifeStyle.***Singleton***);
```

Should of course be

```
container.Register(Component.For<IActionInvoker>()
                                    .ImplementedBy<WindsorActionInvoker>()
                                    .LifeStyle.Transient);
```

Just another reminder to pay closer attention to those Lifestyles.